# Verifying Get and Add Cookie in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, cookies

For the web application I have attempted the following the methods to retrieve a cookie and add it in a later test.

The first test is made up as follows:

```
public void HomePage_Should_Route_To_EntitlementMaintenance_Page()
    {

        WaitFor<HomePage>()
            .EnterBusinessID(Keywords.Keywords.EntitlementsMaintenanceBusinesses.BusinessError)
            .SetSchemeYear(Keywords.Keywords.SchemeYears.2017)
            .ClickGetDataButton()
            .SelectEntitlementMaintenanceAndVerifyOnPage()
            .GetCookie();
    }
```

I have called the GetCookie method to retrieve the cookie for this page

I then proceed to the second test as follows

```
    {

        WaitFor<EntitlementsMaintenance>()
            .AddCookie()
            .EnterBusinessID(Keywords.Keywords.EntitlementsMaintenanceBusinesses.BusinessWithENTError)
            .SetSchemeYear(Keywords.Keywords.SchemeYears.SchemeYear2017)
            .ClickGetDataButton()
            .IsENTWarningDisplayed()
            .Should()
            .BeTrue();
    }
```

For the second test I have called the add cookie method to add the cookie which was retrieved in the first test.

The two cookie methods are made as follows

```
 public Cookie GetCookie()
{            
cookies = DriverProvider.GetDriver().Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed    ("entitlementsmaintenance");

        return cookies;
    }
```

The add cookie method is:

```
public EntitlementsMaintenance AddCookie()
    {
            DriverProvider.GetDriver().Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(cookies);

        return this;

    }
```

Once the test are run I am still seeing behaviour as if the cookie has not been added correctly.

Is there a way I can verify if the cookie has been collected on the first test and being used for the second?

Comment: A test relying on the output of a different test? Ew.

Answer (score 0):

The first test probably runs correctly and gets the cookie, but it seems the second one, when it does

```
public EntitlementsMaintenance AddCookie()
{
    DriverProvider.GetDriver().Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(cookies);
    return this;
}
```

The variable `cookies` is maybe null? I don't know how you achieved passing a variable (either it is class or local one), to the next test. Maybe you should try to see when you `AddCookie(cookies);` the variable has information indeed.